# How can I copy from MobaXTerm and paste into something of external (for example Google)?

Tags: mobaxterm

I would like to copy stuff from MobaXTerm into something external to MobaXTerm, for instance copy a command that I ran in MobaXTerm or a Matlab code opened from MobaXTerm and paste it into Google to search for it. The traditional method does not work since I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> does not work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I copy from MobaXTerm?

> To do Copy/Paste in MobaXterm, you should not use
> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>.
>
> Instead, select the text you want to copy, then use the right mouse
> button to bring up the context menu, and select "Copy" or select
> "Paste" when you are pasting.

Source: [Mobaxterm Configuration | Joint HPC Exchange](https://jhpce.jhu.edu/knowledge-base/mobaxterm-configuration/)

Comment: Thanks, however this does not fix completely what I want... It works if I want to copy something from the MobaXTerm terminal but for instance if I open Matlab and I want to copy an error that it gives into Google how can I do ? Or even viceversa...

Comment: In matlab ctrl + C to copy. ctrl + X to cut. ctrl + V to paste

Comment: Yes but if I want to copy a code of Matlab and paste it in Google ?